# Angular.js selecting from a hash / object

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple dropdown:

```
 {{x}}            
 <select ng-model="x" ng-options="k for k in [1,2,3]"></select>
```

easy: {{x}} will be replaced with the selected value 1, 2 or 3.

But what if my data looks like this?

```
 <select ng-model="x" ng-options="k.a for k in [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]">
```

I want the ones, twos and threes depending on selection but I usually get "{a:1}".

Hm.. [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/OqFpB4souEI) suggests that maybe I won't get what I want. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing just one piece.

If you look at the [docs for `ng-options`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect), there are several forms the comprehension expression can take.

The form you have is `label for value in array`. With this form, when you choose an options, it gives you the entire value of the array item, which in your case is something like `{a: 1}`.

One of the other forms you can use is `select as label for value in array`. You stick an extra expression in from, and the result of ***that*** expression will be bound to your model.

So something like:

```
ng-options="k.a as k.a for k in [...]"
```

Then you'll get the value of the `a` attribute of the selected array item.

[Here's a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/SyCSK/).

Comment: very nice. I had assumed the "as xxx" to be just like the "just a different name" - thing in SQL and therefore had glanced over it.